# kth-value per row in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, vectorization

Given

```py
import torch    
A = torch.rand(9).view((3,3)) # tensor([[0.7455, 0.7736, 0.1772],\n[0.6646, 0.4191, 0.6602],\n[0.0818, 0.8079, 0.6424]])
k = torch.tensor([0,1,0])
A.kthvalue_vectoriezed(k) -> [0.1772,0.6602,0.0818]
```

Meaning I would like to operate on each column with a different k.

Not `kthvalue` nor topk offers such API.
Is there a **vectorized** way around that?
**Remark** - kth value is not the value in the kth index, but the kth smallest element. [Pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.kthvalue)

> `torch.kthvalue(input, k, dim=None, keepdim=False, out=None) -> (Tensor, LongTensor)`
>   Returns a namedtuple (values, indices) where values is the k th smallest element of each row of the input tensor in the given dimension dim. And indices is the index location of each element found.

Comment: Can you clarify how you're ending up with `[1,5,1]`? Shouldn't it be `[1,5,7]`? Also, note that `A` would be invalid, since you're not offering the constructor a valid data type. Please include a *working* [mcve] for the input. Your expected output can of course still be in pseudo-code.

Comment: Also, note that Python is zero-indexed,so `k` should be `torch.tensor([0, 1, 0])` instead.

Comment: ccl please read pytorch docs about kthvalue, you enter k as one above the index you desire

Comment: Edited with a working example, and corrected the desired output of course:)

Comment: Hm I now see what you're trying to do. I thought you simply wanted to index the values at a certain dim.

Comment: A k-th value per row is often referred to as a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need indices into original matrix (if you do, just use fancy indexing for the second return value as well) you could simply sort the values (by last index by default) and return appropriate values like so:

```
def kth_smallest(tensor, indices):
    tensor_sorted, _ = torch.sort(tensor)
    return tensor_sorted[torch.arange(len(indices)), indices]
```

And this test case gives you your desired values:

```
tensor = torch.tensor(
    [[0.7455, 0.7736, 0.1772], [0.6646, 0.4191, 0.6602], [0.0818, 0.8079, 0.6424]]
)

print(kth_smallest(tensor, [0, 1, 0])) # -> [0.1772,0.6602,0.0818]
```

Comment: It's missing the `O(n)` advantage of kthvalue function over nlogn, but it's a great alternative I've missed, if truly kth_value cannot be vectorized.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, but there is no `O(n)` pre-made solution in PyTorch that I'm aware of. You could write your own  [`C++/CUDA extension`](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html) or integrate `numba`/`cupy` (not sure whether and how complicated this approach would be) if this operation is that crucial.